# Imagecache percentage resize

Tags: 7, media

I just noticed imagecache on my Drupal-7 site is not allowing percentages for resizing images.

This is making it impossible to size images to the full width of my header region.

Does anyone know if there is a configuration I might be missing or an add-on module which will allow percentages?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module [ImageCache Actions](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) with a [custom script](https://drupal.org/comment/5448774#comment-5448774):

```php
image_gd_resize($image,$image->info['width']*0.5,$image->info['height']*0.8);
return $image;
```

and there is a [sandbox project](https://drupal.org/node/2189449) that maybe is not ready for production...

---

Update:

[ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) supports **Scale / Resize by percent** since 7.x-1.5

Comment: yes, now imagecache Actions support Resize/scale by percentage :)